# ActiveRecord: Join for number of subobjects of has_one relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I must apologize because I'm relatively new to sql and my request seems relatively easy.

**The source code:**

```
class Garage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car
  scope :active, ...

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drivers
```

One garage is `active` if the belonging car has at least one driver.

**Problem:** `:active` scope must return all garages which has car with more than one driver.

I supposed that the code must be something like:

```
scope :active, joins(:car).where('cars.drivers.num > 0')
```

but unfortunately this throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
scope :active, joins(:car => :drivers).where('COUNT(drivers.id) > 0')
```

My bad, this scope above is probably wrong (a COUNT in a WHERE clause ?!)

Try this instead:

```
scope :active, joins(:car => :drivers).
               select('garages.*').
               group('garages.id').
               having('COUNT(drivers.*) > 0')
```